# Angular JS - response from GET not available in $scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am facing a problem with variables not available in the $scope after a GET request

Route provider has

```
when('/vote/:surveyId', { templateUrl: 'partials/polllist.html', controller: PollListCtrl }).
```

and I have a service.js will following code

```
factory('Vote', function($resource) {
        return $resource('vote/:surveyId', {}, {
            // Use this method for getting a list of polls
                vote : {
                    method : 'POST',
                    params : {
                        surveyId : 'vote'
                    },
                    isArray : true
                },
                getVote : {
                    method : 'GET',
                    isArray : true
                }   
        })
    })
```

I have the following code in PollListCtrl

V

```
ote.vote(voteObj, function(p, resp) {
                console.log("outside --- NNNNOOOOO ERRRORRRRR"+$location);
                if(!p.error) {
                    // If there is no error, redirect to the main view
                    console.log("NNNNOOOOO ERRRORRRRR"+resp);
                    $scope.vote_data = resp;
                    $scope.voted = Vote.getVote({
                        surveyId : surveyId
                    });                 
                    //$location.path('surveys');
                    //$location.path();                 
                } else {
                    alert('Could not create survey');
                }
            });
```

Can you pls help me with the issue..

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you want to specify parameters in a GET resource that way, you have to use an @ to perform the mapping.  Also, you told the resource parameter to use the "vote" variable, but when you tried to call the endpoint, you gave it "surveyId" instead. I kept your definition structure and changed your controller code to match just to keep the changes clear.

Also, you didn't post all of your controller code, so I'm not sure exactly where surveyId (the one you're trying to pass into the route) is coming from; I assume you have it declared somewhere.  But if that's supposed to be a scoped variable, you'll want to prepend it with `$scope.`

```
factory('Vote', function($resource) {
        return $resource('vote/:surveyId', {}, {
                vote : {
                    method : 'POST',
                    params : {
                        surveyId : '@vote'//<= Changed
                    },
                    isArray : true
                },
                getVote : {
                    method : 'GET',
                    isArray : true
                }   
        })
    })
Vote.vote(voteObj, function(p, resp) {
                if(!p.error) {

                    $scope.vote_data = resp;
                    $scope.voted = Vote.getVote({vote : surveyId}); //<=Changed                              
                } else {
                    alert('Could not create survey');
                }
            });
```

Try that and let me know if you still have trouble.